# Debian filesystem permissions

Tags: permissions, filesystems, btrfs

BTRFS disk mounted like this:

```
/dev/sdb        /mnt/disk1     btrfs   noexec,nofail,defaults,compress-force=lzo       0 0
```

disk1 is shared via cifs with 640 permissions. I can't launch any application/script because permissions and noexec mount parameter but when I map this share in windows I can change permissions - right click on file -> preferences -> security tab and add executable permission and thats all right because I am the owner of changing file but I can't understand why from now I can launch exe file (windows app. will launch) on **noexec** btrfs filesystem ?

Debian 9 with btrfs-progs 4.7

Comment: Windows does not care about your Linux permissions and flags. It simply reads file via CIFS protocol and executes it. If you can read it -- you can execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `noexec` flag only applies to the OS which is using that `fstab` entry to mount the relevant partition.  Windows does not use `fstab` and indeed doesn't care about such flags.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to prevent windows from launching executables ?

Comment: Short answer:  no.  Long answer:  There are ways to make it more difficult, but that is beyond the scope of U&L.

Answer (score 0):

to block the run of programs we use windows native Software Restriction Policies

for example : on our 1200 managed clients (xp professional and win 7) we block the folders Documents and Downloads

Comment: Do you mean GPO ?

Comment: no, we dont push policies from the domain controllers to the clients.

Comment: we load on each client some registry keys. google for SRP.  ( GPO is a method, it isn't mandatory )